# How to show toast just after dispatching a successful action in react native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am working on an authentication system. Here when user enter wrong password i want to show toast but the problem it the way i am doing its not working.

I am using react-redux for state management In my app.

Here is how my login flow works
Here when login button is pressed it dispatches `getLogin` action, if it gets error from server side it sends loginError which is a string. That's why i am check it here. `LoginError` is coming from redux store and `loginSuccess` as well.

> Login.tsx

```
const { width: wWidth, height: wHeight } = Dimensions.get("window");



const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  password: Yup.string().required(),
  email: Yup.string().email().required(),
});

const Login = ({ navigation, getLogin, authentication }: LoginProps) => {
  const { toast } = useToast();
  const { loginLoading, loginSuccess, loginError } = authentication;

  const {
    handleChange,
    handleBlur,
    handleSubmit,
    values,
    errors,
    touched,
    setFieldValue,
  } = useFormik({
    validationSchema,
    initialValues: {
      password: "",
      email: "",
      callback: false,
    },
    onSubmit: async (values) => {
      getLogin(values.email, values.password, navigation);
    },
  });

  if (loginError !== "" && loginSuccess === "") {
    console.log("HelloFromIf");
    toast({
      message: "Wrong username or password!",
      bg: "background",
      color: "text",
      accentColor: "main",
      iconFamily: "Feather",
      iconName: "alert-triangle",
      iconColor: "error",
    });
  }
  return (
    <Box
      backgroundColor="primaryText"
      flex={1}
      justifyContent="center"
      alignItems="center"
    >
      <Box
        justifyContent="center"
        alignItems="center"
        height={wHeight / 2}
        width={wWidth}
        flex={1}
      >
        <Box style={{ marginTop: 100 }} height={wHeight / 3} width={wWidth / 2}>
          <Image
            style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%" }}
            source={require("../../../assets/login-logo.png")}
          />
        </Box>
      </Box>
      <Box
        borderTopLeftRadius="l"
        borderTopRightRadius="l"
        width={wWidth}
        backgroundColor="iconBackground"
        flex={1}
      >
        <Box marginHorizontal="l">
          <Box>
            <TextField
              onChangeText={handleChange("email")}
              placeholder="email"
              onBlur={handleBlur("email")}
              error={errors.email}
              touched={touched.email}
            />
          </Box>
          <Box>
            <TextField
              secureTextEntry={true}
              placeholder="Password"
              onChangeText={handleChange("password")}
              onBlur={handleBlur("password")}
              error={errors.password}
              touched={touched.password}
            />
          </Box>
          <LargeButton
            loading={loginLoading}
            onPress={handleSubmit}
            label={"LOGIN"}
          />
          <Box paddingVertical="m" alignItems="center">
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback>
              <Text variant="seeAll">Forgot Password ?</Text>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
          </Box>

          <Box paddingVertical="m" alignItems="center">
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback
              onPress={() => navigation.navigate("SignUp")}
            >
              <Text variant="seeAll">Create new account!</Text>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
          </Box>
        </Box>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
};

function mapStateToProps(state: any) {
  return {
    authentication: state.auth,
  };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any) => {
  return {
    getLogin: (email: string, password: string, navigation: any) =>
      dispatch(userLogin(email, password, navigation)),
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login);
```

> authAction.tsx

```
export const userLogin = (email: string, password: string, navigation: any) => (
  dispatch: any
) => {
  dispatch({
    type: LOGIN_USER_LOADING,
  });
  const base64 = require("base-64");
  const hash = "Basic " + base64.encode("karthik:karthik");
  let data = new FormData();
  data.append("username", email);
  data.append("password", password);
  data.append("grant_type", "password");
  let config: AxiosRequestConfig = {
    method: "post",
    url: _login_user,
    headers: {
      Authorization: hash,
    },
    data: data,
  };
  axios(config)
    .then((res: AxiosResponse) => {
      dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
        payload: res.data,
      });
      const _rest = new restServices();
      _rest.saveToken(res.data);
      navigation.navigate("Home");
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_USER_ERROR,
        error: err,
      });
    });
};
```

> authReducer.tsx

```
import {
  LOGIN_USER_LOADING,
  USER_SIGN_UP_ERROR,
  USER_SIGN_UP_LOADING,
} from "./../actions/constants/authConstant";
import {
  LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
  LOGIN_USER_ERROR,
  LOGOUT_USER,
} from "../actions/constants/authConstant";
import { USER_AUTHORIZED } from "../actions/constants/authConstant";
import { USER_SIGN_UP } from "../actions/constants/authConstant";

export type AuthState = {
  readonly isAuthenticated: boolean;
  readonly userData: {};
  readonly loginLoading: boolean;
  readonly loginSuccess: string;
  readonly loginError: string;

};

const initialState: AuthState = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  userData: {},
  loginLoading: false,
  loginSuccess: "",
  loginError: "",

};

const authReducer = (state = initialState, action: any) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    
    case LOGIN_USER_LOADING:
      return {
        ...state,
        loginLoading: true,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        loginError: "",
        loginSuccess: "",
      };

    case LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthenticated: true,
        loginLoading: false,
        userData: action.payload,
        loginError: "",
        loginSuccess: "User Logged In.",
      };
    case LOGIN_USER_ERROR:
      return {
        ...state,
        loginLoading: false,
        loginError: action.error,
        loginSuccess: "",
      };
    
    default:
      return {
        ...state,
      };
  }
};

export default authReducer;
```

I am not sure weather i am doing it right or wrong please help me solve this issue. This toast show even when login is successfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `useEffect` to perform a side effect when your state updates.

You can replace you current code with this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (loginError !== "" && loginSuccess === "") {
    console.log("HelloFromIf");
    toast({
      message: "Wrong username or password!",
      bg: "background",
      color: "text",
      accentColor: "main",
      iconFamily: "Feather",
      iconName: "alert-triangle",
      iconColor: "error",
    });
  }
}, [loginError, loginSuccess]);
```

The function will run every time either loginError or loginSuccess changes, and display the toast whenever the conditions are met.

By the way, you should probably have a look at this to improve your authentication flow: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow

Comment: its better to use useDispatch and useSelector. useEffect can be error prone

Answer (score 0):

You should put that condition before render
Class component

```
import {useSelector, useDispatch} from 'react-redux'
const { width: wWidth, height: wHeight } = Dimensions.get("window");



const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  password: Yup.string().required(),
  email: Yup.string().email().required(),
});

const Login = ({ navigation, getLogin, authentication }: LoginProps) => {
  const { toast } = useToast();
  const authentication = useSelector(state => state.auth);
  const { loginLoading, loginSuccess, loginError } = authentication;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  

  const {
    handleChange,
    handleBlur,
    handleSubmit,
    values,
    errors,
    touched,
    setFieldValue,
  } = useFormik({
    validationSchema,
    initialValues: {
      password: "",
      email: "",
      callback: false,
    },
    onSubmit: async (values) => {
      dispatch(userLogin(email, password, navigation)) // You call directly your action
    },
  });

  if (loginError !== "" && loginSuccess === "") {
    console.log("HelloFromIf");
    toast({
      message: "Wrong username or password!",
      bg: "background",
      color: "text",
      accentColor: "main",
      iconFamily: "Feather",
      iconName: "alert-triangle",
      iconColor: "error",
    });
  }
  return (
    <Box
      backgroundColor="primaryText"
      flex={1}
      justifyContent="center"
      alignItems="center"
    >
      <Box
        justifyContent="center"
        alignItems="center"
        height={wHeight / 2}
        width={wWidth}
        flex={1}
      >
        <Box style={{ marginTop: 100 }} height={wHeight / 3} width={wWidth / 2}>
          <Image
            style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%" }}
            source={require("../../../assets/login-logo.png")}
          />
        </Box>
      </Box>
      <Box
        borderTopLeftRadius="l"
        borderTopRightRadius="l"
        width={wWidth}
        backgroundColor="iconBackground"
        flex={1}
      >
        <Box marginHorizontal="l">
          <Box>
            <TextField
              onChangeText={handleChange("email")}
              placeholder="email"
              onBlur={handleBlur("email")}
              error={errors.email}
              touched={touched.email}
            />
          </Box>
          <Box>
            <TextField
              secureTextEntry={true}
              placeholder="Password"
              onChangeText={handleChange("password")}
              onBlur={handleBlur("password")}
              error={errors.password}
              touched={touched.password}
            />
          </Box>
          <LargeButton
            loading={loginLoading}
            onPress={handleSubmit}
            label={"LOGIN"}
          />
          <Box paddingVertical="m" alignItems="center">
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback>
              <Text variant="seeAll">Forgot Password ?</Text>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
          </Box>

          <Box paddingVertical="m" alignItems="center">
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback
              onPress={() => navigation.navigate("SignUp")}
            >
              <Text variant="seeAll">Create new account!</Text>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
          </Box>
        </Box>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
};


export default Login;
```

Comment: edit your question and add all your code where you have your submit

Comment: I have updated my question  with complete login have a look

Comment: check my update, read about hooks https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks